# Unable to access API using Refit. Receiving "Response status code does not indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed)."

Tags: .net, api, post, connection, refit

I am working on a .NET API at the moment and I am trying to write NUnit tests, using Refit to connect to my API. When I try to access my API with Refit, I keep receiving an HTTP error code 405, indicating that the method I am trying to access is "not allowed". I have learned from other sources that this might be an issue with POST methods. In that case, how should I correctly use POST methods with Refit? Currently, I am routing all requests through an interface with formatting like this for a POST method, for example.

```cs
[Get("/DBAccess/createpost")]
Task<bool> CreatePost(PostModel model);
```

Thank you.

Comment: [Post("/DBAccess/createpost")]

Answer (score 0):

You have a 'GET' method on your code.
Just change GET by POST on your 'CreatePost':

```
[Post("/DBAccess/createpost")]
```